# Question about the phrase "tap somebody as [a position]"

Tags: phrases, phrase-usage

"[Tap](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/tap_1#:%7E:text=%5Bintransitive%2C%20transitive%5D%20to%20hit,tapped%20me%20on%20the%20shoulder.)"(6. ​[transitive, usually passive] tap somebody (North American English) to choose somebody to do a particular job) is a synonym of "[appoint](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/appoint)" when it means "to select for an office or position", and there is a phrase "tap somebody as [a position]".

However, I encounter this sentence:

> To lead that effort, he has **tapped as his foreign minister Ernesto Araújo**, a Trump-loving antiglobalist who wants to prioritize relations with the United States.
>
> ---[Making Brazil great again: How Jair Bolsonaro mirrors and courts Trump](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/the_americas/making-brazil-great-again-how-jair-bolsonaro-mirrors-and-courts-trump/2018/12/29/df8bf7fa-f1d9-11e8-99c2-cfca6fcf610c_story.html) in the Washington Post (Dec. 31, 2018).

**Question:**

Is this sentence correct in grammar, and is this usage common in English?

In some phrases, you can change the order of words, like "give sth. to sb. = give sb. sth.", but the order above (tap as [a position] sombody) is too awkward, and I never saw such change of order in a phrase before. Is such change of order in a phrase common in English?

**Edit:**

Someone told me that if the clause was "he tapped Ernesto Araujo as his foreign minister, a Trump-loving antiglobalist...", there would be a stylistic weakness with the following clause since the description of Araujo is closest to "foreign minister" and thus the sentence is awkward.

What do you think of such claim?

**Edit 2:**

In another article days after (Jan. 3, 2019), there was also such usage in the Washington Post.

> Trump aides say the president never came close to tapping him(Romney).
>
> --- [Romney asserts his independence from Trump — and Trump’s defenders return his searing criticism of the president](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/romney-asserts-his-independence--and-trumps-gop-critics-see-an-opening/2019/01/02/6f0aa9d6-0ea8-11e9-84fc-d58c33d6c8c7_story.html)

Comment: I wouldn't say it's "common", but "tapped", in this sense, is well-understood in the US.  And I suspect it's more common in the UK.  And "tapped as" is legitimate syntax.

Comment: "Tapped as his foreign minister Ernesto Araújo" equals "Tapped Ernesto Araújo as his foreign minister" with only the slightest change of emphasis.

Comment: It certainly is not common in the UK. I've always understood the US expression to mean "put forward" or "suggested" or "intends to appoint", not referring to an actual appointment.

Comment: I've always thought of *tapped* as a tap on the shoulder, as in the children's game of *Duck, duck, goose* (AmE). But I'm thinking it could be as in tapping a barrel of wine or ale.

Comment: I've always assumed it derived from a knight being tapped on the shoulder with a sword.  And then there were a few overly-dramatic business leaders who would wander a room of underlings and then, from behind, tap the shoulder of a newly selected manager.

Comment: '...  he has appointed/named as his foreign minister Ernesto Araújo ...' is just an acceptable variant of '...  he has appointed/named Ernesto Araújo as his foreign minister   ...'. I'd consider mixing the more formal postponed DO version with the verb 'tapped' perhaps a mixing of registers, but I'm not sure how formal/informal 'tap' in this sense _is_ in N America, In the UK, it sounds ... let's say _unusual_.

Comment: The inversion in the sentence is stylistically correct—for the reason "Someone" told you. If the sentence ended without the appositive, then we would likely use the normal order: *To lead that effort, he has tapped Ernesto Araújo as his foreign minister.* We could also say: *To lead that effort, he has tapped Ernesto Araújo, a Trump-loving antiglobalist who wants to prioritize relations with the United States, as his foreign minister.* But I think you can see that that's a bit inelegant.

Comment: I've always heard it as ["tap _for_" a position.](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/tap+someone+for+something)

Comment: The use is first recorded in 1952 by E. O'Neill *He was tapped for an exclusive Senior Society at the Ivy university* Possibly - OED: Tap (v.) c. To arrest (someone). Also in to tap on the shoulder. slang. 1785 *A tap on the shoulder, an arrest.* 1894   J. G. Littlechild *We instructed him..to hint darkly that he was going to be ‘tapped’—i.e. taken into custody* The history is that a police officer, when making an arrest, had to touch the suspect (usually on the shoulder) to indicate definitively who he was arresting. Thus: to designate someone.

Comment: It looks to me like a pretty straightforward migration from *[publicly] **singled out*** through "tapping on the shoulder" to indicate one's choice for all to see. It probably could and did get coined repeatedly, so looking for a "first use" seems a bit pointless. As to how common it is, or what syntax rules apply to it, I think that's all just Off Topic opinions.